# Weighted degree as primary parameter for attraction/repulsion in Gephi?

Tags: gephi, graph-layout, network-analysis

I'm trying to create a graph that visualizes two companies' (`Company x` and `Company y`) total revenue to a list of Danish municipalities (kommune). I've created an edges table that has the revenue in the weight column:

```
Source;Target;weight
Company x;Aabenraa Kommune;8836320
Company x;Albertslund Kommune;2147954
Company x;Aller›d Kommune;903120
Company x;Assens Kommune;6186345
Company x;Ballerup Kommune;4955805
Company x;Billund Kommune;2185544
Company x;Bornholms Regionskommune;9512399
Company y;Aabenraa Kommune;30164191
Company y;Albertslund Kommune;16142026
Company y;Aller›d Kommune;13849175
Company y;Assens Kommune;24428267
Company y;Ballerup Kommune;21203672
Company y;Billund Kommune;21219891
Company y;Bornholms Regionskommune;23952062
```

I've calculated the weighted degree for all nodes in Gephi, which allows me to have the size and color of the company nodes determined by their weighted Out-Degree (their total revenue to all municipalities), and similarly the size and color of the muncipality nodes determined by their weighted In-Degree (their total expenditure to the two companies).

All this is quite good, but I would also like to be able to let the weighted degree be the primary parameter that decides the notes attraction/repulsion to each other. I.e. I want a company node to be closer to the municipality whom they have the biggest revenue with. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So e.g. weighted in-degree is Total expenditure/in-degree etc.? Could you give the node table as well, it is difficult to make the calculations from inside Gephi